# Customize Bootstrap to 960px wide

Tags: css, resize, width, containers, customization

I want to use Bootstrap to create my newly designed template which is 960px in width. However, I don't know how to customize Bootstrap to resize their container size which is way too large my project.

I have an idea but I'm not sure if it's the right way of doing it. Can I just a new "custom.css" document and  edit the .container class to 960px?

Thanks in advance,
Richard.

Comment: yah. its the right thing to do.

Comment: Are you talking you want to change the break point at which it converts to mobile, or just allowing the "center stage" (`.container`) to be wider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap, by default: The container class has the following `max-width` specified in media query.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    max-width:750px;
  }  
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
  .container{
    max-width:970px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .container{
    max-width:1170px;
  }
}
```

To override this add the following rules to your stylesheet `custom.css` (Make sure that your stylesheet `custom.css` is loading after bootstrap stylesheet `bootstrap.min.css`):

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .container{
    max-width:960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .container{
    max-width:960px;
  }
}
```

You can change the other media query rules too if you want to.

Here is the list of default grid options by bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Answer (score 1):

You can free customize grid system in boostrap follow on home page of boostrap: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints.

Comment: I like this solution because it allows you to customize Bootstrap in a way that they explicitly expose for you, rather than attempting to override their code, which seems less robust and more fraught with potential pitfalls.

Comment: I like this solution as well, the problem I have with it is that i don't know which fields to modify. There are so many of them. I appreciate your help though!